# The algebra of continuous functions on Cantor set

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $C(K)$ be the algebra of continuous functions on Cantor set. Is it possible to prove that $C(K)$ forms an AF-algebra without Bratteli diagram?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure. Regard $K$ as $\{0,1\}^N$ and let $E_n$ for $n\in N$ be the functions in $C(K)$ that depend only on the first $n$ components.

Comment: Could you explain a little more?

Comment: The $E_n$ are an increasing sequence of subalgefbras with dense union, and for each $n$, $E_n$ is algebra isometric to $\ell_\infty^{2^n}$.

Comment: It is completely clear now. Thanks.